# Python: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service ./chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, fedora

I have developed a web scraper with python using Selenium and the Chrome driver. My cloud server has Python 3.7.

The script works great on my local PC. Unfortunately, on my cloud server, when I execute, I get an error that chrome driver does not want to execute, with error status code -11 (I have looked everywhere and never seen that status code).

Chromedriver is on its latest available version.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "harvest.py", line 50, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='./chromedriver')
  File "/home/customer/www/harvest/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/customer/www/harvest/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/serice.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/customer/www/harvest/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service ./chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
```

The siteground cloud server runs on Fedora. Unfortunately, they do not allow me sudo or root access, so I am very limited with my SSH account.

The only issue I can see here is that I do not have Google Chrome installed (only the driver) on the cloud. I am, however, trying to execute the driver with headless option.
I have tried to install the browser, but my limited access to SSH did not allow me to(and, of course, Siteground does not want to help in this regard). So no sudo, no yum install, no dpkg, etc...
Is it possible for me to install Google Chrome via FTP interface? If so how?

Here is the line where the error points to:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.headless = True
---> driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='./chromedriver')
```

If I try to execute chromedriver alone with ./chromedriver, I get the following error:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Is there a solution that I can apply on my end? Or has it reached the point where I just need to change my server?

Comment: can you try and see if using `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")` solves your issue or not

Comment: for selenium to work(even for headless), the browser needs to be installed there as selenium API through chrome driver communicates with the actual browser. can you try if they have firefox or any other browser installed there?